# How to set the _CheckinComment with CSOM (SharePoint)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm looking for a way to set the _CheckinComment. If i try It like this:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File myUploadFile = myList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
ListItem myItem = myUploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
myItem["Title"] = Path.GetFileName(sDocPath);
myItem["_CheckinComment"] = "This is the comment";
myClientContext.Load(myItem);
myClientContext.Load(myUploadFile);
myClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.

I want to change the _CheckinComment (InternalName) and not this:

```
myUploadFile.CheckIn("This is the comment", CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn)
```

Who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535526(v=office.14).aspx), "_CheckinComment" is a read-only server field. So, that explains your error.

Although you didn't specify what you are attempting to do, I think I know as I had my own problem related to this. I think you were annoyed that you couldn't put a check-in comment on upload...and when you use the checkin() method it creates a new version. So, your upload spans two versions (the first is the upload itself with no check-in comment and the second is the addition of the check-in comment)--kind of messy.

The key for me was to use the Publish(string) [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.publish.aspx] and Unpublish(string) methods. This allows you to set the check-in comment for the current file while promoting/demoting the current version to a major of minor. Assuming your document library has major and minor versions, you can apply it as follows:

1. Upload -> Publish(strComment) to create a major version with comment
2. Upload -> Publish("") -> Unpublish(strComment) to create a minor version with a comment.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.publish.aspx